# Why does the standard let functions that don't return compile?

Tags: c, c99

f() does not return even though it's signature say it should.
Why is the reason for allowing this to compiling?
Is there a reason the C standard does not require the compiler to make it fail?

I know that it is Undefined behavior and all, but why is it allowed in the first place?
Is there a historical reason?

```
double f(){}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because this is Undefined behavior. If you compile with strict warnings a good compiler shall point it out for you.

Comment: @AlokSave Yes, but why is it allowed? Is there a historical reason?

Comment: It's pretty easy for the compiler to catch the error, and I can see no reason for allowing it in the first place.

Comment: Any such requirement would burden the compiler to check every possible return path, which is as you say pretty easy for a modern day compiler but was not so easy in pre standardization compilers.

Comment: It's not pretty easy for the compiler. It's pretty easy to check if there's obviously a return, or obviously no return. But for more complicated control flow, it's hard to undecidable (if you permit all functions that don't return because they never halt).

Comment: This question could be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376461/what-actually-happens-when-a-function-with-the-warning-control-reaches-end-o

Comment: @delman Wouldn't forcing every branch in the control flow to have a return allow that?

Comment: In the early days of C, C compilers were not as smart as they can be today because CPUs were slower and memories and storage were smaller. The C specs/standards of those days recognized this problem and allowed problematic code to compile, transforming what could be a compile-time problem into a run-time problem, leaving it to the compiled program's user to deal with it. It's not the only problem of this kind. Unprototyped functions (especially when using K&R syntax) that were allowed until C99 is another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reason the C standard does not require the compiler to make
>   it fail?

By invoking undefined behavior, the C standard allowed the compilers to be less complicated. There is indeed some cases, such as `if` statements, in which it is hard to say whether the function returns a value or not:

```
int f(int n)
{
  if (n > 0) return 1;
}
```

- If I write `f(5)`, it is easy for the compiler to say that the
  function is correct.
- If I write `f(-5)`, it is also easy to detect
  an undefined return value.

But if the argument comes from user input for example, how should the compiler be able to know whether the function returns a value? Since this could both a valid or a wrong program, C standard allows the compilers to do what they want. C is designed to be as smart and simple as possible.

Comment: But, the signature says it accepts ints, so the function should be defined for all int values. Shouldn't it? Why is that difficult to enforce?

Comment: @njr: Well (from my example), if I call `f(5)`, it is easy for the compiler to say that there is no undefined behavior. If I have `f(-5)`, it is also easy to detect the undefined behavior. But if the argument comes from a user input for example, how should the compiler be able to know whether the function returns a value or not?

Comment: At compile time? It knows that n>5 can be false. Could it be to make the executable smaller?

Comment: @njr: Well, he knows that could be wrong. But it could also be a valid program. By invoking undefined behavior, C Standard allows the compilers to do what they want. C is designed to be as smart and simple as possible.

Comment: Could you add that to the answer please

Comment: @njr: it would probably be a bad idea to enforce that if a function takes `int` then it should have defined behavior for all `int` inputs. For example, `int plusone(int i) { return i + 1; }` has undefined behavior for the input `INT_MAX`. That's just how C does business, it doesn't force you to add code to handle all cases, if you don't want to.

Comment: I think `f` and `plusone` are different. `plusone` always returns an `int`, syntactically it is *always* correct although it may be semantically incorrect for a specific input. I use to think that the compiler should always ensure syntactic correctness whereas semantic correctness is beyond its scope. For `f`, it can be easily deduced that there exists at least one path with no return statements, hence the function is not guaranteed to be syntactically correct. It is not necessary to analyze all possible inputs though.

Comment: @ArunSaha: the requirement to return a value (if the caller uses the return value), *is* a semantic restriction in C99, not a syntactic constraint. `f` is syntactically correct. The question amounts to, "why isn't it a syntactic constraint?". `plusone` is intended solely as an example to njr (whose day it is for suggesting potential syntactic constraints ;-)) why there's no syntactic requirement that every input value must have defined behavior. You're right that this is a different issue from why there's no syntactic requirement that every path must have a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler *could* certainly analyze all code paths for the function and reject the program if it cannot prove that the function *always* returns a meaningful value. I suppose the reason the standard does not mandate it is that in the old days compilers were much less sophisticated than we work with today.

Of course using the return value of such a function is undefined behavior:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to tell that your function will reach the end without returning a value. It doesn't return *and* it doesn't call any code that could prevent it reaching the end (like `abort()`).

In fact your program does *not* have undefined behavior in C99, since the missing return value isn't used by the caller. 6.9.1/12:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
>   function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undeﬁned.

So your code has questionable style, but is well-defined.

The C++ standard changes the rule and remarks on that change in `[diff.stat]`. It says that the C version of the rule is to support code that was written back in the days when C didn't distinguish between `int` return and `void` return. So the reason your code has defined behavior in the first place is "legacy". That said, AFAIK C has always distinguished between `double` return and `int` return, so it could probably have made it UB for a function returning `double` to fall off the end, had it been done at the right time.

Leaving aside whether the return value is used, consider a tricker function:

```
double f() {
    if (g()) exit();
}
```

This function also contains no return statements, but doesn't reach the end of the function if in fact `g` always returns a true value or doesn't return at all. So this function should be accepted even if its return value is used, on the general C standard principle that you're expected to know what you're doing and mean what you say. If `g` is defined in a different TU then you probably know more about it than the compiler does.

Even if it weren't for the legacy reasons, I'm pretty sure that the standard simply cannot be bothered adding text in order to define what non-return scenarios compilers are required to detect. It's left to quality of implementation -- if it can be determined at compile time that your function cannot possibly avoid UB then maybe the compiler will warn anyway despite no diagnostic being required. For that matter, it will occasionally warn when behavior is defined on the general C *implementer's* principle that some things are so daft that no user could reasonably mean them.

Comment: Is reaching the end without returning UB by itself? Even if the return value is not accessed?

Comment: @Jon: good point. No, in C it's not. In C++ it is (6.6.3/2). I say this as the reason for my error, not an excuse ;-)

Comment: And I was asking merely to make sure that I didn't have the wrong impression :-). On another point, the compiler could demand that you either add a sane `return 0;` at the end or else make it `void f()` -- either one or the other makes more sense no matter what `g()` does at runtime. But it's certainly not in the C-spirit of que sera, sera.

Comment: @Jon: the compiler could certainly warn if you don't add `return 0` (or perhaps some implementation-defined `__unreachable`). But it has to accept conforming code or else it's not a conforming C implementation, so it will only go so far to prevent you doing something stupid.

Comment: Of course, my point was that if you wrote the standard today it wouldn't be unreasonable to demand this. But for C it's as if written in stone, changing this today would probably break more programs than there are grains of sand on a beach.

Comment: @Jon: or anyway more than no programs.

Comment: Returning without specifying a value may also be sensible in cases where a parameter selects what action a function will perform, and where some actions would generate meaningful return values and others wouldn't.  If there were a means of explicitly indicating "return arbitrary meaningless value" it may be reasonable to require that all reachable branches either return a normal value or an explicitly-meaningless one, but requiring programmers to write code that would compel a compiler to generate machine code to load a value the caller should ignore doesn't seem particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler can not tell if the function returns at runtime or not.

Comment: The question may be confusingly worded.  I think the OP was trying to ask why he didn't get a compiler error when his function is supposed to return a double but has no path which actually returns anything.

Comment: But it can tell there is no `return` while the function asserts that it returns a `double`. That's a pretty serious contradiction.

Comment: @Jon It can tell that no `return` keyword occurs. Telling if all paths actually hit a `return` is much, much harder.

Comment: According to my experience compilers issue a warning if a path without return value is found, but maybe it's not standardized.