# visual Studio Strange Behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I write a code of c++ in visual studio 2010 as a example for my junior which look like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<< "How are Your";
}
```

i didn't understand how this program build and execute without a return statement if any one can explain it for me ??

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376461/what-actually-happens-when-a-function-with-the-warning-control-reaches-end-o

Answer (score 9):

Without a return statement in `main` function, it's default to `return 0;`

**§ 3.6.1**

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function
>   (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling
>   std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches
>   the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is
>   that of executing return 0;