# Why wont this object get created? c++

Tags: c++, class, object

Here is my main. All I am trying to do is create an object of the class file, this is probably a very noobish question so sorry, just need to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the student adventures game.\n";

    Player player1();
}
```

Comment: +1 because there is people who prefer to downvote over teaching.

Comment: @Theraot: my downvote was to teach, to teach that this was a bad question. How does he detect that this object is not created? It should compile (cannot know for sure without `PLayer.h`), he doesn't ever use player1, so what's the exact error?

Comment: This is a duplicate and should be closed. I'm in a minority that thinks that just because something is a duplicate it shouldn't be downvoted

Comment: @KillianDS thank you by explaining your downvote, was it that hard? If this was asked, it is because the asker knows no better, a downvotes alone aren't going to fix that problem. I understand that you only answer "good question", but those who ask "bad questions" are those who need more help. Also, as for not using the variable, I guess that is his take on being minimal on examples.

Comment: @Everybody, just post your complains on meta =P

Comment: +1 for *not* having `using namespace std` at the top of your code.

Comment: +1 For a clear and concise question, even if it does happen to be a dupe.

Answer (score 14):

You declared a function which return Player type, see [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

To define an object, try update

```
Player player1();
```

to

```
Player player1;
```

Comment: Downvoter, explain plz

Comment: ahh, I knew it would be obvious, thanks a lot you've really helped me out :)

Comment: @Benjamin-Cox See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work for details

Comment: Doesn't forgetting to return an integer in ``main`` also cause an error?

Comment: by default, it returns 0 in main, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853114/visual-studio-strange-behavior/14853204#14853204)

Comment: @halflings no, main will return 0 by default.

Comment: @halflings, Worth noting that it's undefined behaviour not to return from other non-void functions, not a compiler error.

Comment: Moving from java I guess ...

Comment: @billz didn't downvote since I've confused them too (until recently), but I've been told a few days ago that this is **not** the most vexing parse. That would look like `Player player1(string name())` or something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use the parenthesis when declaring an object without parameters, or else the compiler will think you're declaring a function that returns a `Player` and that takes no parameter.

Comment: I always wondered what the return 0 was for lol, and yes thats got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hope the edit is okay, I removed the irrelevant (& wrong) part.