# Loop calling the function just once C++

Tags: c++, function, loops

I have a problem with this code, I inserted a loop so the function `listOfSeats` is always being called and the program never stops running. The problem is it just runs once and i cant guaranteed that the values that I changed in the array seat are changed. I don't know why this is happening please help.
When I added a debugger to see why it crashes i got this [ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYWCr.png)and [ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3oBH.png). Please help i dont really understand what it means.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
string listOfSeats();
const int arraySize = 20;

int main() {
    while(true) {
        cout << "These are the type of seats we offer during the flight and their current status:\n";
        cout << "(LW) Left Window\n(AL) Aisle left\n(AR) Aisle Right\n(RW) Right Window\n\n";
        listOfSeats();
    }
}

string listOfSeats() {
    string typeOfSeat;
    int numOfSeat;
    static string seat[ arraySize ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
        seat[ i ] = "Available";
    cout << setw( 5 )<< "Seat" << setw( 10 ) << "Status" <<endl;
    for ( int lw = 0; lw < 5; ++lw )
        cout << setw( 4 ) << "LW"<<lw+1 << setw( 12 ) << seat[ lw ] << endl;
    for ( int al = 5; al < 10; ++al )
        cout << setw( 4 ) << "AL"<<al-4 << setw( 12 ) << seat[ al] << endl;
    for ( int rl = 10; rl < 15; ++rl )
        cout << setw( 4 ) << "RL"<<rl-9 << setw( 12 ) << seat[ rl] << endl;
    for ( int rw = 15; rw < 20; ++rw )
        cout << setw( 4 ) << "AL"<<rw-14 << setw( 12 ) << seat[ rw] << endl;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the type of seat you want to reserve (just the characters on brackets):";
    for(;;) {
        cin >> typeOfSeat;
        if (typeOfSeat=="LW") {
            cout <<"You have chosen a Left window seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(typeOfSeat=="AL") {
            cout <<"You have chosen an Aisle left seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(typeOfSeat=="AR") {
            cout <<"You have chosen an Aisle right seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(typeOfSeat=="RW") {
            cout <<"You have chosen a Right window seat.";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout <<"Invalid option entered. \nPlease enter a valid option:";
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nFrom the list presented above. Enter the number of the type of seat you want to reserve\n(just the number following the characters):";
    for(;;) {
        cin >> numOfSeat;
        if (numOfSeat==1) {
            cout <<"You have reserved the number "<< numOfSeat<<" "<<typeOfSeat<<" seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(numOfSeat==2) {
            cout <<"You have reserved the number "<< numOfSeat <<" "<<typeOfSeat<<" seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(numOfSeat==3) {
            cout <<"You have reserved the number "<< numOfSeat <<" "<<typeOfSeat<<" seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(numOfSeat==4) {
            cout <<"You have reserved the number "<< numOfSeat <<" "<<typeOfSeat<<" seat.";
            break;
        }
        else if(numOfSeat==5) {
            cout <<"You have reserved the number "<< numOfSeat <<" "<<typeOfSeat<<" seat.";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout <<"Invalid option entered. \nPlease enter a valid option:";
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (typeOfSeat=="LW") {
        seat[ numOfSeat-1 ]="Reserved";
    }
}
```

Comment: on which inputs does this happen? Have you tried attaching a debugger to see if your program crashes?

Comment: Please use "switch-case" to ensure only a single logic to run based on criteria. Too many if-else creates confusion. For second if/else, you can simply include the numOfSeat in your message without needing any if/else

Comment: i just did it and it delivers me a message that i dont really undertand. Im updating the post with a screenshot of what it says so you can help

Comment: tip: you can use free tools such AStyle to fix the code formatting before posting the code on SO.

Comment: Your `listOfSeats` is supposed to return `string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What (actually) happens, when a function with the warning "control reaches end of non-void function" is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376461/what-actually-happens-when-a-function-with-the-warning-control-reaches-end-o)

Answer (score 5):

`listOfSeats` initializes the seats to available each time it's called.

*Edit*: Also, I didn't notice when I first posted this, you need replace the function result type `string` with `void`, or else add a `return` statement. Currently you have Undefined Behavior when the function returns. Upping the warning level for your compiler, e.g. `-Wall` for g++ or `/W4` for Visual C++, will most likely produce a diagnostic about that.

Comment: Well several questions were asked: "Why do the values not change", "why is the loop only running once" and "why is the program crashing". This is already contradictory. The close votes are for exactly that: Unclear problem description. I don't agree with closing right away on these grounds, but the question definitely has problems on this end.

Comment: It's unreasonable to require perfect questions. With a perfect understanding, required for formulating perfect questions, there would be no need to ask. I'd say this question was Good Enough by a good margin: actual code posted, screenshots, attempt (though imperfect) at explaining what was wrong.

Comment: Nobody is expecting perfect questions. But avoiding contradictions in your description of the program behavior surely wouldn't be unreasonable?

Comment: I think there is also something to be said about *minimal code example*. I know this is not so bad, and not worth a close, but the MCVE page explicitly says *When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back*. Most of the printing and setup code could have been removed to make this question easier to read. This is definitely a dump of everything the OP has. This is not grounds for a close, but could easily be grounds for a downvote if one were so inclined.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, don't give up. Remember the reason why you signed up for SO. :) As long as there are beginners (including me), there will always be a reason for you to stay.

Comment: FWIW I agree that there is too much "this is too long for a MCVE" (even if clearly minimal), "start learning C++ by reading a book" (when there is only a minor mistake) and other cosmetic complaints being thrown at reasonable questions. And yeah, asking for clarification would be better. But maybe this is also too much expectation of perfection.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Do you know why there are so many complains about code sample not being minimal? Because the main goal of this site is not that a person that has some questions gets an answer. The main goal is that if next person has same problem, he/she finds this question and answer. How do you expect another person with missing return statement find this question?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec How would you suggest to change this question/code so people with the same issue can actually find it (_before_ finding the cause of their problem)? I'm very curious.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I guess pasting compiler warning/error emitted by compiler on this code would suffice.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Hardly. The warning is pretty clear itself and it is beyond easy to find an explanation if it is for some reason not obvious what it means. As seen here, the warning was not enabled or it was ignored and the result is UB, potentially a crash. That is as nonspecific a behavior to search for as it gets. In short, I think that you cannot edit this question to help others with the same problem because the problem is unspecific and and the solution is immediately obvious (or explained better elsewhere) once you identify the issue.

Comment: @MaxLanghof "As seen here, the warning was not enabled or it was ignored". And that makes it a low quality question. I suggest closing it.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the function 'string listOfSeats()' with return type string, but you do not return within the scope of the function. Alter the function to return nothing (a.k.a. void) at line 5 and 19 of the code.

In a nutshell, alter this:

```
string listOfSeats() //has return type string
```

to this:

```
void ListOfSeats() //has return type void
```

at line 5 and 19.

Comment: Yeah that helped now the loop works, thx. Now I just need to know how to save the reserved seats, so it appears reserved when the loop calls it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flsh your cin. Its going in infinite loop.

Replace you else loop with this -

```
    else {
        cout <<"Invalid option entered. \nPlease enter a valid option:";
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        continue;
    }
```

Include below header -

```
#include <limits>
```