# I have written the code of affine cipher in C. It correctly encrypts/decrypts the uppercase letters but incorrectly encrypts/decrypts lowercase letter

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

# define MAX_LENGTH 100 

int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    GCD(b, a%b);
}

struct Pair{
    int x, y;
};

struct Pair Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) {
        struct Pair answer;
        answer.x = 1;
        answer.y = 0;
        return answer;
    }

    struct Pair small_answer = Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(b, a%b);
    struct Pair answer;
    answer.x = small_answer.y;
    answer.y = small_answer.x - (a/b)*small_answer.y;

    return answer;
}

void Encryption(char Plaintext[], char Ciphertext[], int a, int b) {
    int temp_1, temp_2, i;
    i = 0;

    while(Plaintext[i] != '\0') {
        temp_1 = Plaintext[i];

        if(temp_1 >= 65 && temp_1 <= 90) {
            temp_2 = (a*temp_1 + b)%26;
            Ciphertext[i++] = 'A' + temp_2;
        }else if(temp_1 >= 97 && temp_1 <= 122) {
            temp_2 = (a*temp_1 + b)%26;
            Ciphertext[i++] = 'a' + temp_2;
        } else if(temp_1 == 32) {
            Ciphertext[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }

    Ciphertext[i] = '\0';
}

void Decryption(char Ciphertext[], char Decrypted_Plaintext[], int a, int b) {
    struct Pair inverse;
    int temp_a_inverse;
    inverse = Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(26, a);
    temp_a_inverse = inverse.y;

    if(temp_a_inverse < 0) {
        temp_a_inverse = temp_a_inverse + 26;
    }

    int temp_1, temp_2, i;
    i = 0;

    while(Ciphertext[i] != '\0') {
        temp_1 = Ciphertext[i];

        if(temp_1 >= 65 && temp_1 <= 90) {
            temp_2 = ((temp_1 + 26 - b)*temp_a_inverse)%26;
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = 'A' + temp_2;
        } else if(temp_1 >= 97 && temp_1 <= 122) {
            temp_2 = ((temp_1 + 26 - b)*temp_a_inverse)%26;
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = 'a' + temp_2;
        } else if(temp_1 == 32) {
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }

    Decrypted_Plaintext[i] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char Plaintext[MAX_LENGTH], Ciphertext[MAX_LENGTH], Decrypted_Plaintext[MAX_LENGTH];
    char c;
    printf("Enter the plaintext: ");
    int i = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        Plaintext[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    Plaintext[i] = '\0';
    printf("Choose any number from the given numbers: ");
    int a, b, temp_a;

    for(int j = 1; j <= 26; j++) {
        temp_a = GCD(26, j);

        if(temp_a == 1){
            printf("%d |", j);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    srand(time(0));
    b = (rand()%(26)) + 1;

    Encryption(Plaintext, Ciphertext, a, b); //Encrypting Plaintext
    Decryption(Ciphertext, Decrypted_Plaintext, a, b); //Decrypting Ciphertext
    printf("The Plaintext is: %s\n", Plaintext);
    printf("a = %d || b = %d\n", a, b);
    printf("The Ciphertext is: %s\n", Ciphertext);
    printf("The Decrypted Plaintext is: %s\n", Decrypted_Plaintext);
    return 0;
}
```

I have written the code of affine cipher in C. It correctly encrypts/decrypts the uppercase letters but incorrectly encrypts/decrypts lowercase letter So, when I tested it for uppercase letters it works fine, but when I try to test it for lowercase letters it fails, everytime. So, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Note: `GCD` does not return a value when `b != 0`.

Comment: Consider using the character literals `'A'`, `'a'`, `'Z'` and `'z'` rather than their numeric values, as C does not exclusively use ASCII or UTF-8, and it makes the intent of the code more clear

Comment: @GovindParmar Using `'A'`, `'a'`, etc. does not make thing clearer yet if code is not using  ASCII or UTF-8, program has other issues as `a - z` is not certainly consecutive.

Comment: @Omen, save time and enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Just replace `GCD(b, a%b);` with `return GCD(b, a%b);` to correct *that* problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12376461/238704.

Comment: It's a style thing, but rather than `struct Answer answer; answer.x = 0; answer.y = 1; return answer;` consider using a compound literal: `return (struct Answer){ .x=0, .y=1 };`

Answer (score 2):

Trying out your code with an uppercase word and a lowercase word netted the undesired behavior with the lowercase word.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Decipher/bin/Release$ ./Decipher 
Enter the plaintext: HELLO
Choose any number from the given numbers: 1 |3 |5 |7 |9 |11 |15 |17 |19 |21 |23 |25 |
3
The Plaintext is: HELLO
a = 3 || b = 12
The Ciphertext is: ULGGP
The Decrypted Plaintext is: HELLO
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Decipher/bin/Release$ ./Decipher 
Enter the plaintext: Hello
Choose any number from the given numbers: 1 |3 |5 |7 |9 |11 |15 |17 |19 |21 |23 |25 |
3
The Plaintext is: Hello
a = 3 || b = 14
The Ciphertext is: Wfaaj
The Decrypted Plaintext is: Hmttw
```

Even when doing some simple debugging, I could not tie down the exact behavior problem with the lowercase characters other than there seemed to be an issue with the "temp_2" calculation multiplication/calculation going on in the lowercase if/else blocks for both the encryption and decryption.

Since the end result is to select a character at a time and apply and encryption/offset calculation to that character, the simplest solution was to always treat the character as an uppercase character, perform the encryption or decryption, and then calculate its offset from the lowercase character 'a' instead of the uppercase character 'A'.

Following are the blocks of code showing off the refactored steps.

First off, per the good comments, the "Greatest Common Denominator" function was corrected to return an integer from a recursive call to the function.

```
    int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return GCD(b, a%b);     /* Refactored per good comments */
}
```

Then the formulas within the encryption and decryption functions were refactored to handle characters as uppercase values and then add in the "character 'a'" offset.

```
void Encryption(char Plaintext[], char Ciphertext[], int a, int b)
{
    int temp_1, temp_2, i;
    i = 0;

    while(Plaintext[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp_1 = Plaintext[i];

        if(temp_1 >= 65 && temp_1 <= 90)
        {
            temp_2 = (a*temp_1 + b)%26;
            Ciphertext[i++] = 'A' + temp_2;
        }
        else if(temp_1 >= 97 && temp_1 <= 122)
        {
            temp_2 = (a*(temp_1 - 32) + b) % 26;    /* Refactored to treat character as uppercase       */
            Ciphertext[i++] = 'a' + temp_2;         /* Offset value is applied to lowercase reference   */
        }
        else if(temp_1 == 32)
        {
            Ciphertext[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }

    Ciphertext[i] = '\0';
}

void Decryption(char Ciphertext[], char Decrypted_Plaintext[], int a, int b)
{
    struct Pair inverse;
    int temp_a_inverse;
    inverse = Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(26, a);
    temp_a_inverse = inverse.y;

    if(temp_a_inverse < 0)
    {
        temp_a_inverse = temp_a_inverse + 26;
    }

    int temp_1, temp_2, i;
    i = 0;

    while(Ciphertext[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp_1 = Ciphertext[i];

        if(temp_1 >= 65 && temp_1 <= 90)
        {
            temp_2 = ((temp_1 + 26 - b)*temp_a_inverse)%26;
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = 'A' + temp_2;
        }
        else if(temp_1 >= 97 && temp_1 <= 122)
        {
            temp_2 = ((temp_1 - 32 + 26 - b)*temp_a_inverse)%26;    /* Refactored to treat character as uppercase       */
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = 'a' + temp_2;                /* Offset value is applied to lowercase reference   */
        }
        else if(temp_1 == 32)
        {
            Decrypted_Plaintext[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }

    Decrypted_Plaintext[i] = '\0';
}
```

Following were a couple of tests showing the terminal output with this refactoring.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Decipher/bin/Release$ ./Decipher 
Enter the plaintext: Hello
Choose any number from the given numbers: 1 |3 |5 |7 |9 |11 |15 |17 |19 |21 |23 |25 |
3
The Plaintext is: Hello
a = 3 || b = 14
The Ciphertext is: Wniir
The Decrypted Plaintext is: Hello
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Decipher/bin/Release$ ./Decipher 
Enter the plaintext: Welcome home
Choose any number from the given numbers: 1 |3 |5 |7 |9 |11 |15 |17 |19 |21 |23 |25 |
7
The Plaintext is: Welcome home
a = 7 || b = 21
The Ciphertext is: Gkhwcok fcok
The Decrypted Plaintext is: Welcome home
```

This possibly is not as elegant of a solution as hoped for, but it does offer up a simplified solution by stepping back to determine where issues can be simplified.

The takeaway from this is probably to delve some more into some "C" tutorials as they pertain to character arrays, encryption methods, and ASCII character sets.

Comment: After reviewing the refactored code, it did come to me that the underlying issue was that the offset value between any given uppercase character and its lowercase counterpart was "32" and so skews the usage of the "modulo 26" operation.  So refactoring the code as I did addressed that skewing issue as would subtracting "6" from the lowercase character value (32 - 6 = 26).